# Minimum insertion to make a string palindrome

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

My idea is to find the Length of Longest Palindromic subsequence and subtract it from the string length. Will it work. If no please give an explanation?

Comment: it may works just fine

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> find the Length of Longest Palindromic subsequence and subtract it
>   from the string length.

This will work obviously.

Another way can be - reverse the original string `s` into `s'` and find the LCS (longest common subsequence) of `s` and `s'`. The answer is: `length(s) - LCS(s, s')`